# How do I get formatted value of environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, string-formatting, file-location, command-execution

In my webapplication I want to allow administrators to execute system commands like:

```
        Process proc = Runtime
            .getRuntime()
            .exec("cmd.exe /C dir C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final_JAX-RS_BookStore\\"+subDir);
```

I now retrieve the JBoss home directory via:

```
String SERVER_HOME = System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME");
```

Unfortunately, this returns me `C:\Program Files (x86)\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final_JAX-RS_BookStore` instead of: `C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final_JAX-RS_BookStore\\` so that the `.exec(...)` command won't work anymore.

How can I format this file path properly?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following should work:

```
String SERVER_HOME = "\"" + System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME") + "\"";
```

where the double quotes would allow the spaces within the path.

Comment: Oh ... thanks, it works!
I thought, that I need the quotes before and after `Program Files (x86)` too. 
Thanks a bunch!